# Difference between `gnome-shell --replace` and r in Alt+F2

Tags: gnome-shell, restart

Does typing `r` in **Enter a Command** dialog that appears after <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> key combination is used do the same thing as opening a terminal and executing `gnome-shell --replace &`?

Specifically, do they execute the same code "behind the scenes"?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would you please add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `r` in the "*Enter a Command*" command dialog that appears after using keybinding <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd> [restarts GNOME Shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet#Developer_tools):

[image: screenshot]

while `gnome-shell --replace` ["replaces the running window manager"](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gnome-shell.1.html).

In the first case Gnome Shell is already running. In the second case there may be another window manager running before.