# Is there an exact command for restarting GNOME Shell in Ubuntu 20.04 corresponding to Alt + F2 + 'r' + Enter?

Tags: gnome-shell

Is there a way to restart GNOME Shell other than by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

With respect to the question, I have gone through [Difference between `gnome-shell --replace` and r in Alt+F2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034306/difference-between-gnome-shell-replace-and-r-in-altf2), but I didn't get what I was looking for.

I am looking for a command which exactly does what <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> do.

Please note that I am not willing to do the `gnome-shell -- replace` command...

I did check both the things <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> and `gnome-shell --replace`...
There is a lot of difference, I found...

Comment: Can you list the important differences between `Alt+F2` `r` `Enter` and running `gnome-shell -r`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Alt + F2 + r + Return (Gnome Shell Reset) through the Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159737/how-to-execute-alt-f2-r-return-gnome-shell-reset-through-the-terminal)

Comment: @DanMan nop.. not looking for simulation.. mainly the question is about When Alt F2 r is done.. whats the command executed. so that that command can be made as a shortcut..

Comment: Plus one for making me glad about Unity desktop whilst still having gnome terminal nautilus gedit gsettings and dbus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command for doing this is (*Tested in Ubuntu 20.04 Only*)

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Meta.restart(_("Restarting…"))'
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-from-command.html

Answer (score 3):

As [Diego F. Rodríguez V. mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/1216775/618353), there is no way to access that from a terminal. However,

```
killall -3 gnome-shell
```

is very close and keeps your active session in tact. It sends a QUIT signal (SIGQUIT), and since gnome-shell is set to start automatically whenever X is up, it technically does a similar thing.

```
kill -SIGQUIT PID
kill -3 PID
kill -QUIT PID
```

can be done as well, but it requires a PID (process ID) as an argument, which can be found via

```
ps x | grep "gnome-shell"
```

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to restart gnome shell programmatically because it seems there is some kind of memory leak in Ubuntu 19.10. `gnome-shell` starts consuming a little over 200 MB but after several hours of use it can reach more than 900 MB.

`alt+f2,r,enter` solves the problem gracefully. A small "restarting" message shows up. The change is almost unnoticeable, all windows maintain their position and running programs keep their state. Only the desktop background seems to flicker while it reloads.

When using `gnome-shell --replace` some programs are killed with all the work in them lost, the windows that survive may change their position and several parts of the screen appear to be redrawn. I also tried `killall gnome-shell` with similar results.

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to access this functionality from the command line as it is embedded deep in the gnome-shell code for the [RunDialog](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/master/js/ui/runDialog.js) GObject:

#### gnome-shell > js > ui > runDialog.js [37]

```
this._internalCommands = {
    'lg': () => Main.createLookingGlass().open(),
    'r': this._restart.bind(this),
    ...
```

Comment: I read this article about the memory leak in gnome-shell but I guess the fix hasn't made it yet into Ubuntu: https://feaneron.com/2018/04/20/the-infamous-gnome-shell-memory-leak/

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me is to invoke the call from the [Cinnamon source code](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/blob/master/src/cinnamon-global.c#L1130).
Works on 5.4.10. Also does not prompt for fallback mode.

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.Cinnamon /org/Cinnamon org.Cinnamon.Eval string:"global.real_restart()"
```